# Inserting an Image in cventry in moderncv

Tags: graphics, moderncv

I am using `moderncv` to create my CV.
In the *Experience* section, I enter each element by

```
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}
```

I would like to insert a small logo of the company or university in the left column, i.e. just below the years.
How can I do it?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about)

Answer (score 5):

You can use the standard `\includegraphics` command from the `graphicx` package (the width of the box containing the year information is `\hintscolumnwidth` which defaults to `0.175\textwidth` in the `classic` style); a little example:

```
\documentclass{moderncv}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\moderncvstyle{classic}

\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle
\cventry{year--year\\\includegraphics[width=\hintscolumnwidth]{ctanlion}}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}

\end{document}
```

[image]

CTAN lion drawing by Duane Bibby.