# Insert logo in \cventry for modercv (classic style)

Tags: graphics, align, moderncv

I'm using `moderncv` for my CV. I tweaked with `moderncvstyleclassic.sty` quite a bit and I'm almost there in terms of the result I want. There's just 1 last thing I cannot solve: I would like to add a logo at the right-end side of the `\cventry`.

At the moment, I created a new command, `\cventrylogo`:

```
\renewcommand*{\cventrylogo}[8][.25em]{%
  \cvitem[#1]{#2}{%
    {\bfseries#3}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{}}{}{, {\slshape#4}}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{}}{}{, #5}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{, #6.}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#7}{}}{}{\hfill \includegraphics[scale=0.25]{#7}}%
    \strut%
    \ifx&#8&%
      \else{\newline{}\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}\small#8\end{minipage}}\fi}}
```

which then I use like this:

```
\section{Experience}
\cventrylogo{2015}{Short Term Scientific Collaborator}{M\'et\'eosuisse}{Payerne}{Switzerland}{logo_meteosuisse}{}
\cventrylogo{2009--2014}{PhD. in Physical Chemistry}{ETH}{Zurich}{Switzerland}{logo_eth}{}
\cventrylogo{2006--2008}{Process Development Engineer}{STM S.p.A.}{Agrate Brianza}{Italy}{logo_st}{}
\cventrylogo{2004--2005}{Internship}{Alenia Spazio S.p.A.}{Turin}{Italy}{logo_tas}{}
```

The results is as follows:

[image]

I already had a look at similar questions, [1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/148192/adding-pictures-to-moderncv) and [2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/101766/inserting-an-image-in-cventry-in-moderncv), but this is not exactly what I want. There are 2 problems. First the images are aligned at the bottom and I would like to have them aligned at the center of the text and second, I would love to have the option of specify the size of the images in the `\cventrylogo` command, but implement this is beyond my abilities. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

I answered to this question myself with help from Harish Kumar, providing a MWE for use.

Comment: Try `\newcommand{\cventrylogo}[9][.25em]{%
  \cvitem[#1]{#2}{%
    {\bfseries#3}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{}}{}{, {\slshape#4}}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{}}{}{, #5}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{, #6}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#7}{}}{}{%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#8}{}}{\hfill \raisebox{-0.5\height}{\includegraphics[width=6mm]{#7}}}%
      {\hfill \raisebox{-0.5\height}{\includegraphics[width=#8]{#7}}}}%
    \strut%
    \ifx&#9&%
      \else{\newline{}\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}\small#9\end{minipage}}\fi}
      }`.

Comment: @HarishKumar: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately that does not work. I get this error: `! LaTeX Error: Command \cventrylogo already defined.`

Furthermore, I do not understand the last bit of it, when you pass the width as a parameter. I should use `{\hfill \raisebox{-0.5\height}{\includegraphics[width=6mm]{#7}}}` OR `{\hfill \raisebox{-0.5\height}{\includegraphics[width=#8]{#7}}}}`, right?

Comment: Use `\renewcommand` instead of `\newcommand`.  YoWith above, you should use `\cventrylogo{2006--2008}{Process Development Engineer}{STM S.p.A.}{Agrate Brianza}{Italy}{example-image-a}{6mm}{}` or `\cventrylogo{2004--2005}{Internship}{Alenia Spazio S.p.A.}{Turin}{Italy}{example-image-a}{}{}` (with no width).

Comment: If you give a full mwe (starting from `\documentclass`) and ending at `\end{document}`, I can test it.

Comment: @HarishKumar: I'll try the suggested modification and post a MWE as soon as I get home. Here at work I do not have access to my CV. Thanks for the answer

Comment: @Harish Kumar or Riccardo I., it would be great if you could add an answer, so it can be accepted and this question is removed from the list of unanswered questions.

Comment: @ph0t0nix: Done, the answer is there and selected as accepted. Sorry for the delay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It now works as I wanted, using the command `\cventrylogo` defined as this:

```
\renewcommand{\cventrylogo}[9][.25em]{% 
\cvitem[#1]{#2}{% 
  {\bfseries#3}% 
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{}}{}{, {\slshape#4}}% 
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{}}{}{, #5}% 
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{, #6.}% 
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#7}{}}{}{% 
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#8}{}}{}{\hfill \raisebox{-0.5\height}{\includegraphics[width=#8]{#7}}}}%
  \strut% 
  \ifx&#9&% 
    \else{\newline{}\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}\small#9\end{minipage}}\fi} }
```

here is the MWE, for further reference for whom it may use it:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[scale=0.8]{geometry} 

\name{Riccardo}{I.}
\title{Title title}
\address{XXX}{place ville}{}
\phone[mobile]{+00~(0)~00~000~00~00}    
\email{xxx.yyy@gmail.com} 

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{Experience}
\cventrylogo{2015}{Short Term Scientific Collaborator}{M\'et\'eosuisse}{Payerne}{Switzerland}{logo_meteosuisse}{16mm}{}
\cventrylogo{2009--2014}{PhD. in Physical Chemistry}{ETH}{Zurich}{Switzerland}{logo_eth}{25mm}{}
\cventrylogo{2006--2008}{Process Development Engineer}{STM S.p.A.}{Agrate Brianza}{Italy}{logo_st}{18mm}{}
\cventrylogo{2004--2005}{Internship}{Alenia Spazio S.p.A.}{Turin}{Italy}{logo_tas}{20mm}{}

\end{document}
```