# How to insert a logo in moderncv and keep it on the right side of the page?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, moderncv

Ok the title is not exactly clear, so I will try to be clearer here.

I have succesfully added a logo in a cventry using the answer provided in [this tread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/241966/insert-logo-in-cventry-for-modercv-classic-style). The command that I used is

```
\newcommand*{\cventrylogo}[8][.25em]{%
  \cvitem[#1]{#2}{%
    {\bfseries#3}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{}}{}{, {\slshape#4}}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{}}{}{, #5}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{, #6.}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#7}{}}{}{\hfill \includegraphics[scale=0.25]{#7}}%
    \strut%
    \ifx&#8&%
      \else{\newline{}\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}\small#8\end{minipage}}\fi}}
```

This works, but the result that I get is in the image that follows:[image: First example]

As you can see, the logo is there but if the text preceding it is long, it gets pushed to the next line. I'd like to avoid that behavior and have the logo fixed on the right side of the page, with the text naturally going on the next line.

I've prepared an image of what I'd like to achieve:
[image: Second Example]

How should I modify the command to get this result?

Here is a minimum code example if you need to test things:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[scale=0.85]{geometry}

\name{John}{Doe}
\address{Address}{Address}{Country}
\phone[mobile]{+1234567890}
\phone[fixed]{+1234567890}
\email{email@emal.com}
\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{picture}

%cventrylogo
\newcommand{\cventrylogo}[9][.25em]{%
\cvitem[#1]{#2}{%
  {\bfseries#3}%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{}}{}{, {\slshape#4}}%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{}}{}{, #5}%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{, #6.}%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#7}{}}{}{%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#8}{}}{}{\hfill \raisebox{-0.5\height}{\includegraphics[width=#8]{#7}}}}%
  \strut%
  \ifx&#9&%
    \else{\newline{}\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}\small#9\end{minipage}}\fi} }
\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{Work Experience}

\section{Education}
\cventrylogo{Date1 - Date2}{Very long name just to make things clearer}{Name of the institution}{Address of the institution}{}{logo}{16mm}{Very long and interesting description of what I did there}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There you go:

[image]

I used a `minipage` approach. First I check if the argument `#7` is present, if it is, create a minipage with width `\linewidth-#8-1em` (the `1em` is atrbitrary, just to keep a small space between the text and the image).

Then the content is typeset normally.

Then, another check is repeated of the existence of `#7` and, if positive, the first minipage is closed and another with width `#8` is opened and the image is placed.

#### Edit:

I had to patch the `\cvitem` macro to correct the vertical alignment. Because I used `[t]`op aligned `minipage`s on the right side of the `\cvitem`, LaTeX aligned the baseline of the left side with a `\vspace{0pt}`, which caused the misalignment. So I patched the `\cvitem` macro to include a `minipage` with the same `[t]`op alignment.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[scale=0.85]{geometry}

\name{John}{Doe}
\address{Address}{Address}{Country}
\phone[mobile]{+1234567890}
\phone[fixed]{+1234567890}
\email{email@emal.com}
\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{example-image}

\expandafter\patchcmd\csname\string\cvitem\endcsname
   {\hintstyle{#2}}
   {\hintstyle{\begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\tabcolsep\relax}\vspace{0pt}#2\end{minipage}}}
   {}
   {}%

%cventrylogo
\newcommand{\cventrylogo}[9][.25em]{%
\cvitem[#1]{#2}{%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#7}{}}%
  {}{%                                        V-V arbitrary space
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-#8-1em}%
    \vspace{0pt}%
  }%
  {\bfseries#3}%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{}}{}{, {\slshape#4}}%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{}}{}{, #5}%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{, #6.}%
  \strut%
  \ifx&#9&%
    \else{\newline{}\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}\small#9\end{minipage}}\fi
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#7}{}}%
  {}{%
    \end{minipage}\hfill%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{#8}%
    \vspace{0pt}%
    \includegraphics[width=#8]{#7}%
    \end{minipage}%
  }%
  } }
\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{Work Experience}

\section{Education}
\cventrylogo{Date1 - Date2}{Very long name just to make things clearer}{Name of the institution}{Address of the institution}{}{example-image}{16mm}{Very long and interesting description of what I did there}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks this is great! Just a quick question: as you can see from the image you uploaded, the description is not vertically aligned with the date anymore, is there any way to change this behavior and keep the vertical alignment?

Comment: @randomlygenned Done!

Comment: this fixes that problem but cause every other element to be vertically misaligned. Like the section titles (they should be at the same level of the blue lines) and every other entry that does not use the `\cventrylogo` command, like a normal `\cventry`. Thanks a lot though, I will try and see if I can work something out!

Comment: Ok I found a solution. If anyone is interested, I inserted a negative value into `\vspace{}`, so that the `\minipage` is shifted up. The value that works for me is -8pt. It probably isn't the best or most elegant solution, but it works!