# Two columns on a \newcommand

Tags: macros, cv

I'm making my CV. I have the following command declared:

```
\newcommand{\cvevent}[4]{%
  {\large\color{emphasis}#1\par}
  \smallskip
  \textbf{\color{accent}#2}\par
  \smallskip
  {\small\makebox[0.5\linewidth][l]{\faCalendar\hspace{0.5em}#3}%
  \ifstrequal{#4}{}{}{\makebox[0.5\linewidth][l]{\faMapMarker\hspace{0.5em}#4}}\par}
  \medskip
}
```

Here is a Minimum Working example of what I have:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand{\locationsymbol}{\faMapMarker}
\newcommand{\cvevent}[4]{%
  {\large#1\par}
  \smallskip
  \textbf{#2}\par
  \smallskip
  {\small\makebox[0.5\linewidth][l]{\faCalendar\hspace{0.5em}#3}%
  \ifstrequal{#4}{}{}{\makebox[0.5\linewidth][l]{\faMapMarker\hspace{0.5em}#4}}\par%
  }
}
\newcommand{\divider}{\textcolor{body!30}{\hdashrule{\linewidth}{0.6pt}{0.5ex}}\medskip}

\begin{document}
\cvevent{Cisco Systems}{Service Provider for AMX}{November 2017 -- April 2018}{Buenos Aires, Argentina}

\end{document}
```

With that I was able to do the following:

[image]

I would like to add an image as a second column like the following:

[image]

To sum up, I would like to add an image aligned to the right that takes the same height than the 3 lines on the left and that is passed as a 5th argument (and if there's no 5th argument then don't put anything.

PS: It would probably be necessary to move the "location" phrase closer to the calendar to make all fit as the document is already on two columns.

Comment: Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: there I updated the question. Hope is better now.

Comment: @AgustinBarrachina Something to look at: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/413768/how-to-insert-a-logo-in-moderncv-and-keep-it-on-the-right-side-of-the-page?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have made a small update to your macro to get what you want:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/413768/how-to-insert-a-logo-in-moderncv-and-keep-it-on-the-right-side-of-the-page?noredirect=1&lq=1
\newcommand{\locationsymbol}{\faMapMarker}
\newcommand{\cvevent}[7]{%
    {\large#1\hfill\par}
    \smallskip
    {\vspace{#3em}\textbf{#2}}  \ifstrequal{#4}{}{}{\hfill\makebox[0.5\linewidth][c]{\protect\includegraphics[width=#4cm]{#5}}}\par
    \smallskip
    {\small\makebox[0.5\linewidth][l]{\faCalendar\hspace{0.5em}#6}%
        \ifstrequal{#7}{}{}{\makebox[0.5\linewidth][l]{\faMapMarker\hspace{0.5em}#7}}\par%
    }

}
\newcommand{\divider}{\textcolor{body!30}{\hdashrule{\linewidth}{0.6pt}{0.5ex}}\medskip}

\begin{document}
    \cvevent{Cisco Systems}{Service Provider for AMX}
    {-3}{2}{example-image-a}{November 2017 -- April 2018}{Buenos Aires, Argentina}
\end{document}
```

with which you will get:

[image]

In addition to your existing macro, I added a few more inputs to play with the spacing. In particular, I modified your `\cvevent{event1}{event2}{event3}...{event7}`. Here `event3` [em] describes the vertical spacing between `event1` and `event2`. And, `event4` decribes the image width in `[cm]`. This is a negative space and it is `~1.5-2 times the width of event4`. More importantly, `event5` is your image.

To add more, I also included the `graphicx` package for convenience.

> **Note**: the sole-purpose of `event3` is to allow you to play with the vertical spacing of your `event2` with respect to the size of your desired image which is `event5` (in this case). It is worthwhile to stress that if you suppose intend to use the `height` parameter of an image, you can indeed add that as an event as well.
>
> All further suggestions and improvements are welcome.