# How can I correctly vertical align text and image in \cvline of moderncv?

Tags: moderncv

I am using `casual` cv of the `moderncv` package.

I added an image using the following 2 codes:

```
\adjustbox{height=1em}{\adjustimage{height=3.5em,valign=t,set depth=0pt}{LOGO1.png}}
```

and

[The solution offered here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/413768/)

With the first code I got:
[image]

And with the second this:
[image]

Ideally, I would like to have something like:
[image]

Any suggestions:

---

Compilable Code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme[blue]{casual}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
\usepackage[super]{nth}
\usepackage[scale=0.8]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3.25cm}


%newcventry
\newcommand{\newcventry}[9][0.25em]{%
    \cvitem[#1]{#2}{%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#7}{}}%
            {}{%                                        V-V arbitrary space
                \begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-#8-1em}%
                \vspace{-0.7em}%
        }%
        {\bfseries#3}% Title
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{}}{}{\newline {\slshape#4}}% Name of the institution
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{}}{}{, {\slshape#5}}% City
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{, {\slshape#6}}% Country
        \strut%
        \ifx&#9&% description
            \else{\newline{}\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}\small#9\end{minipage}}\fi
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#7}{}}% image
        {}{%
        \end{minipage}\hfill%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{#8}% width of image
    \vspace{-0.7em}%
    \includegraphics[width=#8]{#7}%
    \end{minipage}%
  }%
  } }


\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}
\address{Somewhere}{Along there}
\mobile{+1 (800) 555-5555}
\email{my@email.com} 

\extrainfo{
\parbox{6cm}{
\centering
\httplink[\faLinkedin~John Doe]{www.linkedin.com/in/john-doe/}
\footsymbol \httplink[\faXing~John Doe]{www.xing.com/profile/John_Doe/} 
\httplink[\faGithub~JohnDoe]{github.com/JohnDoe}
\footsymbol \httplink[\faStackOverflow~John Doe]{stackoverflow.com/users/12345678/john-doe}
}}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Work Experience}
\cvline{xx.20xx - xx.20xx}{\textbf{Title}\hfill
\adjustbox{height=1em}{\adjustimage{height=3.5em,valign=t,set depth=0pt}{LOGO1.png}}
\newline
\textit{Company, That Location, Fancy City} \newline 
Very long and interesting description of what I did there. Responsible for \underline{\textbf{this}} and \underline{\textbf{that}} - this is just a very very very long text that has no relevance what so ever. Responsible for \underline{\textbf{this}} and \underline{\textbf{that}} - this is just a very very very long text that has no relevance what so ever.}

\newcventry{Date1 - Date2}{Very long name just to make things clearer}{Name of the institution}{Address of the institution}{number 6}{LOGO1.png}{11em}{Very long and interesting description of what I did there. Responsible for \underline{\textbf{this}} and \underline{\textbf{that}} - this is just a very very very long text that has no relevance what so ever. Responsible for \underline{\textbf{this}} and \underline{\textbf{that}} - this is just a very very very long text that has no relevance what so ever.}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If you want complete control over the placement don't use `wrapfig`. And don't use the `center` environment inside of `wrapfigure` or similar environments such as `figure` or `table`.

Comment: @Skillmon, okay, if I don't use them, how can I get the desired result?

Comment: Did you saw question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/413768 ? Duplicate? BTW: `\cvline` is outdated, now it is `\cvitem` ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## New answer

One can use `insbox` to place the graphic (`insbox` is similar to `wrapfig` in it's effect but does so with less ado and therefore exact positioning is easier with it. Still it adds `\@InsertBoxMargin` on top of the image, which results in imperfect alignment with what you want. So I set `\@InsertBoxMargin` to 0pt and add the padding myself with the macro `\EnlargeBox`, which gets 2 aguments. The first is a token list. If that list contains `l` the box will be enlarge to the left by `\InsertBoxMargin`, if it contains `r` to the right. If it contains `t` on top and if it contains `b` on the bottom. The second argument is the material which is to be typeset inside of a `\hbox`.

It will only work for the current `\cvline`/`\cvitem`.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme[blue]{casual}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
%\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
\usepackage[super]{nth}
\usepackage[scale=0.8]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3.25cm}
\input{insbox}
\usepackage{grabbox}

\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}
\address{Somewhere}{Along there}
\mobile{+1 (800) 555-5555}
\email{my@email.com} 

\extrainfo{
\parbox{6cm}{
\centering
\httplink[\faLinkedin~John Doe]{www.linkedin.com/in/john-doe/}
\footsymbol \httplink[\faXing~John Doe]{www.xing.com/profile/John_Doe/} 
\httplink[\faGithub~JohnDoe]{github.com/JohnDoe}
\footsymbol \httplink[\faStackOverflow~John Doe]{stackoverflow.com/users/12345678/john-doe}
}}
\makeatletter
\newlength\InsertBoxMargin
\InsertBoxMargin=\@InsertBoxMargin
\@InsertBoxMargin=0pt
\newsavebox\EnlargeBox@box
\long\def\afterfiAn\else#1\fi#2{\fi}
\long\def\afterfiBy\fi#1{\fi#1}
\newcommand\IfTokenInList@define[1]
  {%
    \def\IfTokenInList@test##1#1##2\q@stop
      {%
        \if\relax\detokenize{##2}\relax
          \afterfiAn
        \else
          \afterfiBy
        \fi
      }%
  }
\newcommand\IfTokenInList[2]
  {%
    \IfTokenInList@define{#1}%
    \IfTokenInList@test#2#1\q@stop
  }
\newcommand\EnlargeBox[1]
  {%
    \begingroup
    \grabbox\EnlargeBox@box[\IfTokenInList{l}{#1}{\hskip\InsertBoxMargin}]%
    \hbox[\IfTokenInList{r}{#1}{\hskip\InsertBoxMargin}]%
      {%
        \IfTokenInList{t}{#1}
          {%
            \ht\EnlargeBox@box
              \dimexpr\InsertBoxMargin+\ht\EnlargeBox@box\relax
          }%
        \IfTokenInList{b}{#1}
          {%
            \dp\EnlargeBox@box
              \dimexpr\InsertBoxMargin+\dp\EnlargeBox@box\relax
          }%
        \box\EnlargeBox@box
        \endgroup
      }%
  }
\makeatother



\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Work Experience}
\cvline{xx.20xx - xx.20xx}{%
  \InsertBoxR{0}{\EnlargeBox{lb}{\includegraphics[width=.23\textwidth]{example-image-duck}}}
\textbf{Title}
  \newline 
\textit{Company, That Location, Fancy City} \newline 
Responsible for \underline{\textbf{this}} and \underline{\textbf{that}} and
also everything else that is interesting}

\cvline{xx.20xx - xx.20xx}{
\textbf{Title} \newline 
\textit{Company, That Location, Fancy City} \newline 
Responsible for \underline{\textbf{this}} and \underline{\textbf{that}}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

## Old answer

Using `adjustbox` to set the image with zero depth and top aligned. It will not take up vertical space this way, so might overlap with other contents.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme[blue]{casual}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
\usepackage[super]{nth}
\usepackage[scale=0.8]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3.25cm}

\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}
\address{Somewhere}{Along there}
\mobile{+1 (800) 555-5555}
\email{my@email.com} 

\extrainfo{
\parbox{6cm}{
\centering
\httplink[\faLinkedin~John Doe]{www.linkedin.com/in/john-doe/}
\footsymbol \httplink[\faXing~John Doe]{www.xing.com/profile/John_Doe/} 
\httplink[\faGithub~JohnDoe]{github.com/JohnDoe}
\footsymbol \httplink[\faStackOverflow~John Doe]{stackoverflow.com/users/12345678/john-doe}
}}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Work Experience}
\cvline{xx.20xx - xx.20xx}{
\textbf{Title}\hfill
\adjustimage{width=.23\textwidth,valign=t,set depth=0pt}{example-image-duck}
  \newline 
\textit{Company, That Location, Fancy City} \newline 
Responsible for \underline{\textbf{this}} and \underline{\textbf{that}}}

\cvline{xx.20xx - xx.20xx}{
\textbf{Title} \newline 
\textit{Company, That Location, Fancy City} \newline 
Responsible for \underline{\textbf{this}} and \underline{\textbf{that}}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That worked, until the test was too long, the text then was over the image, is there a way to then make the text automatically start a new line as soon as it hits the image?

Comment: I tried different solutions, but still was not able to do what I want... I edited the question, I hope it is clearer now.

Answer (score 0):

There is always the *right way*, and the **working way**... so I am pretty sure there is a nice solution, more elegant.

Here I simply added a `\vspace{-4ex}` and removed that `wrapfigure`.

[image: negative space]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme[blue]{casual}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
\usepackage[super]{nth}
\usepackage[scale=0.8]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3.25cm}

\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}
\address{Somewhere}{Along there}
\mobile{+1 (800) 555-5555}
\email{my@email.com} 

\extrainfo{
\parbox{6cm}{
\centering
\httplink[\faLinkedin~John Doe]{www.linkedin.com/in/john-doe/}
\footsymbol \httplink[\faXing~John Doe]{www.xing.com/profile/John_Doe/} 
\httplink[\faGithub~JohnDoe]{github.com/JohnDoe}
\footsymbol \httplink[\faStackOverflow~John Doe]{stackoverflow.com/users/12345678/john-doe}
}}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Work Experience}
\cvline{xx.20xx - xx.20xx}{
        \begin{flushright}
        \vspace{-4ex}
        \includegraphics[width=0.23\textwidth]{example-image-a}
        \end{flushright}}
{\vspace{-18ex}
\textbf{Title} \newline 
\textit{Company, That Location, Fancy City} \newline 
Responsible for \underline{\textbf{this}} and \underline{\textbf{that}}

\textbf{Title} \newline 
\textit{Company, That Location, Fancy City} \newline 
Responsible for \underline{\textbf{this}} and \underline{\textbf{that}}
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, but how can I pull the text up as well?

Comment: Like this? Check new edit. However, this solution is not the correct one. Might not work always and might cause problems at the end of the page...

Comment: No, not like that. Like this -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/hU5HK.png